# Disable user interaction during activityindicator. React-Native

Tags: react-native, activity-indicator

I want to disable user interaction when the activity indicator is running. The user should not be able to type again in the TextInput and disable touchableopacity button.

```
 render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
      <Image
        source={require("./background-image.jpg")}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={styles.backdrop}
      />
    </View>

    <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
      <View style={styles.subContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require("./logo.png")} />

        <TextInput
          // editable={!this.props.isLoginLoading}
          style={styles.input}
          ref={"input1"}
          placeholder="Enter your mobile number"
          maxLength={10}
          onChangeText={value => this.setState({ mobilenumber: value })}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          // activeOpacity={this.getOpacity()} //newly added
          onPress={this.onPress}
        >
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      {this.props.isLoginLoading && (
        <View style={styles.indicator}>
          <ActivityIndicator color={"blue"} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

}
}

> Below shows the design for the above code, styles.js

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
  },

  backgroundContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  },

  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

  subContainer: {
    alignItems: "center"
  },

  backdrop: {
    flex: 1
  },

  image: {
    marginBottom: Metrics.screenHeight * 0.075,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    width: Metrics.screenWidth * 0.35,
    height: Metrics.screenHeight * 0.25
  },

  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: Metrics.screenWidth * 0.03,
    width: Metrics.screenWidth * 0.626,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey"
  },

  button: {
    width: Metrics.screenWidth * 0.626,
    height: Metrics.screenHeight * 0.06,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#8c0d04",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },

  buttonText: {
    padding: Metrics.screenHeight * 0.0165,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

  indicator: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    // width: "100%",
    // height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
    // borderWidth: 5,
    // borderColor: "yellow"
  }
});

export default styles;
```

I used dimensions to get the screen height and screen width according to the device size and added style to the activity indicator to by writing position to 'absolute' but still I'm able to access the text input as well the button click. I want to achieve the following thing when the user clicks the login button, I need to show the activity indicator below the Login button and I have to disable user interaction during the activity indicator.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way you can achieve this.

1. If you want ActivityIndicator **below of button** then just remove view which contains **{{flex:1}**} style. and only give marginTop style to the parent view of ActivityIndicator. For that, you have to disable TextInput and button manually. Please see below code.

   export default class Example extends Component {

   ```
       onPress() {
           if (!this.props.isLoginLoading) {
              // skip if isLoginLoading is true
           }

       }
       getOpacity() {
           if (this.props.isLoginLoading) {
               return 1;
           }
           return 0
       }
       render() {
           return (
               <View style={styles.container}>

                   <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
                       <Image source={require('./background-image.jpg')} resizeMode='cover' style={styles.backdrop} />
                   </View>

                   <View>
                       <View>
                           <Image
                             style={styles.image}
                             source={require('./logo.png')}
                         />
                       </View>

                       <View style={styles.textinputview}>
                           <TextInput
                               editable={!this.props.isLoginLoading} //do editable false when loading is true
                               style={styles.input}
                               ref={'input1'}
                               placeholder='Enter your mobile number'
                               maxLength={10}
                               onChangeText={value => this.setState({ mobilenumber: value })}
                           />
                       </View>

                       <View style={styles.touchableview}>
                           <TouchableOpacity
                               activeOpacity={this.getOpacity()} //set activopacity to 1 to indicate button is disable, when loading is true
                               onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>
                               <View style={styles.button}>
                                   <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                               </View>
                           </TouchableOpacity>
                       </View>


                   </View>
                   {this.props.isLoginLoading &&
                       <View
                           style={{
                               marginTop:10
                           }} >
                           <ActivityIndicator color={'blue'} />
                       </View>
                   }
               </View>
           );
       }
   }
   ```

   2. just remove view which contains flex:{1} style. which will include ActivityIndicator in the center of the screen

      return (

      ```
          <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
              <Image source={require('./background-image.jpg')} resizeMode='cover' style={styles.backdrop} />
          </View>

          <View>
              <View>
                  <Image
                      style={styles.image}
                      source={require('./logo.png')}
                  />
              </View>

              <View style={styles.textinputview}>
                  <TextInput
                      style={styles.input}
                      ref={'input1'}
                      placeholder='Enter your mobile number'
                      maxLength={10}
                      onChangeText={value => this.setState({ mobilenumber: value })}
                  />
              </View>

              <View style={styles.touchableview}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
                      <View style={styles.button}>
                          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                      </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
          </View>
              {this.props.isLoginLoading &&
                  <View
                      style={{
                              position: 'absolute',
                              left: 0,
                              right: 0,
                              top: 0,
                              bottom: 0,
                              width:'100%',
                              height:'100%',
                              justifyContent: 'center',
                              alignItems: 'center'
                      }}>
                      <ActivityIndicator color={'blue'} />
                  </View>
              }
      </View>
      ```

      )

Comment: I've tried this, but still I have access to my TextInput field and button click. I don't know why , may be there's some problem in my design :/

Comment: can you please share the code of your whole design?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try it. It may help you and let me know if any issue in this solution.

Comment: The first method works properly but the second one is still not working. Now it's just a single textinput and a button so I can prefer the first method but when it comes to a single form with many texts and button action the 2nd method comes handy but I still don't know what's the problem there is no error.

Comment: have you removed the view which contains style {{flex:1}} (above {this.props.isLoginLoading && this line) for the second method?

Comment: In second method, you also have to remove view with {flex:1}. because the purpose of flex:1 is to specify the length of the item, relative to the rest of the flexible items. so,in your case, when you use activity indicator in flex:1 view it covers rest of the screen (below of textiput and button), so that you are able to edit text in textInput. If you are still not clear then give background color to it and you can see the difference.

Comment: @VinayNarayankutty I have updated my answer for the second method. Just replace your render method with that. I test this code and working for me.

Comment: Hey I changed both the render and style code a little. And one thing when I add a border to the activity indicator it works.

Comment: @VinayNarayankutty great..!